# Get back to a reference of a tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got something to the effect of this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
       <table>
          <tr>
             <td><a href="#" class="fav">click me</a></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

I have a click event in jquery for my anchor tag with class "fav":

```
$(".fav").click(function(){
  var parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

This gives me a reference to the `tr` within my 2nd table (the table within the `td`).  I'd like to get a reference back to the `tr` in my initial table.  Pictured highlight shows where I have a reference.  Arrow shows where I'd like to get a reference.

[image]

There are plenty of other tables on the page.

Comment: if you just want the outer parent tr, use again a `closest('tr')`

Comment: you could add a specific class to your row then $(this).closest('tr.classname');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**.parents( selector )**](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) function:

```
$(".fav").click(function(){
  var parentRow = $(this).parents("tr:eq(1)");
  // or $(this).parents("tr").eq(1);
  // or $($(this).parents("tr")[1]);
  // or $($(this).parents("tr").get(1));
});
```

Comment: How this differs from `closest('tr')`

Comment: When you use `parents(selector)` function it will get all parent elements in given selector as array. In this case it works much faster than `closest` function which loops through all the sibling nodes.

Comment: The question here is not regarding `Performance` it's about `Getting correct tr element`

Comment: @Tushar it would get the correct `tr` I have used it many times.

Comment: use `$(this).parents('tr').eq(1)` to avoid double wrapping of $

Comment: This ended up being the best solution that worked for me.  Thanks zazu

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are selecting the closest TR, which is the one in the inner table. To get the closest TR in the outer table, you have to find that outer table first:

```
$(".fav").click(function(){
    var parentRow = $(this).closest('table').closest('tr');
});
```

Comment: wouldnt this find the second table?

Comment: `closest` crawls the DOM from the inside to the outside. What do you mean by second table? The inner or outer one? This snippets first finds the inner table and then goes on searching for a parent TR of that inner table.

Comment: It would find the tr in the first table. But if your tables are nested more than one deep then this would not always work .

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck If you do not know how many tables are nested inside each other, one shouldn't use `closest` as this is just a guess. When dealing with an unknown number of nesting levels, one should set a class name to the most outer table for reference, and walk up to a TR, that is a direct child of the (implicitly added) TBODY of the TABLE with that class name.

Comment: @feeela, I agree. Just pointing it out in case anyone is unaware.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the `<tr>` that is a parent. [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpWOyY?editors=101)

```
$(".fav").click(function(){
  var parentRow = $(this).closest('tr').parents('tr')[0];
  console.log(parentRow)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
var parentRow = $(this).closest('table').closest('tr');
```